ERC-20 Tokens Stuck on MIST Multisig Contract on the Polygon Network
Help!  I can't get access to these tokens.... I have ERC-20 tokens attached to a MIST multisig contract on the polygon network.  Here's a contract similar to mine (by not mine).   This might actually be the "original" mist multisig contract address, created by Gavin Wood:
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x5cb5F46a655C02889172323760d12d0e5D83CDAf
and the corresponding contract code on the Ethereum mainnet where this thing was originally created:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x5cb5F46a655C02889172323760d12d0e5D83CDAf#code
Ultimately, I'd like to be able to transfer the tokens to a regular polygon address (at which point I should be able to bridge them over to the Ethereum mainnet.)   I was able to perform a similar operation without issue on the Ethereum mainnet, through etherscan, by going to the contract address, clicking on contract->write_contract->execute, connecting to the main signature account on metamask, putting in the correct info in the execute fields in etherscan, hitting "write", and verifying in metamask.  No problems.
I want to do something similar in polygonscan to make the transfer on that chain.   However... you'll notice when you click on the polygonscan address link above, you won't see any "contract" button.  I'm not a developer... I don't know if this means that the contract was never deployed on polygonscan, or maybe it was just never "verified".   Since that wasn't done prior to the tokens being sent to the polygon contract address, is it possible it can be verified now... and who can do that?  Or are they doomed to be stuck there forever?
I also tried accessing my polygon contract through MEW.   It looked like it was doing something, but no tokens were ever sent from the contract to final address.   I'm not sure if this is because of the same reason (i.e. contract never being deployed/verified on polygon), or there was some other issue.
Any help recovering my tokens would be greatly appreciated!

To recover ERC-20 tokens from a MIST multisig contract on the Polygon network, verify the contract on PolygonScan and execute transactions via the contract interface. Ensure connectivity to the Polygon network in MetaMask and use Ethereum interfaces like MyEtherWallet

Thank you.  I wasn't sure if verification is needed.  Sounds like it is based on your response.   I actually did try to verify with code I pulled from etherscan but it didn't work.  Probably because the version it was compiled with was so old it wasn't even available on the drop down menu.   Though the error message didn't give me that impression.  I'm wondering if I'll have to reach out to the polygonscan owners to see if they can provide the older compiler version.
